# Fortran Opcode Map? Or "Big O" notation or something similar?

Tags: fortran, big-o, fortran90, fortran77, opcode

I am looking for some type of map or file that will illustrate the amount of work the computer must do to run certain intrinsic functions and loops in Fortran. For example: the amount of decisions needed to run a basic if-then statement checking a boolean(or logical). And how many decisions needed to calculate the basic arithmetic functions such as addition and multiplication.

I know in Assembly it is typically called an OpCode Map, but I realize the timing will be different based on the speed of the computer, so I am looking for something more similar to the "Big O" notation for algorithms.

My main problem is that I am mapping the location of a particle through time with 10000+ time steps and writing the information to a file to then graph the trajectory from. I am curious to see what the specific time lag is going to be in this program, i.e. do if statements inherently take more decisions than do loops? I would like to keep my code as modular and syntactically simple as possible without bogging down programs (especially in the future) that generally take 4+ hours to run on a supercomputer.

Comment: The answer might be "O(1) for all intrinsic functions". Do you have any example for which it's obviously incorrect? If yes, please include it in your question. This will clarify what you need.

Comment: With a decent optimizing compiler code replacing an if statement with a do loop that does the same thing is going to generate machine code that performs the same, if not is exactly the same. I suggest not worrying about the cost of individual statements and instead worry about the Big O cost of the algorithms you're implementing with those statements.

Answer (score 0):

An opcode map is a table that maps machine code bytes to insn mnemonics.  Maybe you're thinking of a table of instruction timings, like [Agner Fog's](http://agner.org/optimize/)?  Very few instructions have data-dependent timing.  Division in many CPUs is variable-latency, with shorter latency for simpler operations.

If you want to know about making programs run faster, you should read Agner Fog's guides to optimizing C++, and apply that to Fortran.  I forget how much high-level stuff he covers (like cache-blocking, aka loop tiling).

Comment: Your link does not work, I got a server not found error. Definitely not my internet connection so must be the link.

Comment: @Kelly: oops, had og not org.  It's the answer to so many performance questions that I just type it, instead of opening it and pasting it.